# WebSphere MQ Explorer does not show queues after successful connection

Tags: ibm-mq

I have a strange problem with WebSphere MQ Explorer 7.x.

I have configured the MQ Explorer for a proper connection with the queue manager. It worked well for a few months, and you could see, in the tree on the left, under queue managers, a listed node named "Queues". Clicking that opened a list of queues on the right.

But right now, I'm not able to list those queues, not even see the node "Queues", as shown in the screenshot below.

I tried to refresh the view (Ctrl+R, F5), reset perspective. Nothing helps.

How can I fix that?

I tried with v7.1 and v7.5.

[image: WebSphere MQ Explorer screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem in the following way.

1. Right clicked on `Queue Managers` node.
2. Selected `Show/Hide Queue managers...`.
3. Hidden my queue manager and applied the change.
4. Shown your queue manager and applied the change.
   Queue manager appeared in the list on the left.
5. Clicked on the manager node in the list to connect.
   `Queues` node appeared.

Answer (score 0):

Click on IBM WebSphere MQ on the navigation panel, you will see a list of icons (on the right window) that indicate the possible states of your Queue Manager.

If your Queue Manager is "Running but disconnected from WebSphere MQ Explorer" you might be connected with a user that has no rights to see the Queues.